# Twitter Bootstrap - how to add some more margin between tooltip popup and element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have not tried anything since I can't understand where space between tooltip and element is made/added from bootstrap, normally tooltip is really near the element who triggers the tooltip event.

I just would like to make the tooltip opening little bit away from the element, to add some more margin from tooltip and element I mean.

I would like to understand how to do this in css if possible and if is possible to make it both for right, left, top, bottom tooltips.

Hope question is clear.

This is how tooltips looks on my app:

[image]

and this is what I would like to do and how it should look afterwards:

[image]

Comment: i'll post images to be more clear

Comment: Does not work with default options, you have to use a other plugin or change the script code to your needs.

Comment: good, if i need a work around i can use jquery, but i need to know how to grab tooltip and add some margin more

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is the default CSS for a tooltip on top :

```
.tooltip.top {
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin-top: -3px;
}
```

You can override it in your own CSS :

```
.tooltip.top {
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Note this code will only work work a tooltip on top, you'll nedd to adapt the CSS for the 3 other orientations :

```
.tooltip.top    { margin-top: -10px; }
.tooltip.right  { margin-left: 10px; }
.tooltip.bottom { margin-top: 10px;   }
.tooltip.left   { margin-left: -10px; }
```

Comment: oh this is awesome testing it out

Answer (score 5):

Here is the complete Bootstrap 4 solution

```
.bs-tooltip-top {
    top: -10px !important;
}

.bs-tooltip-right {
    left: 10px !important;
}

.bs-tooltip-bottom {
    top: 10px !important;
}

.bs-tooltip-left {
    left: -10px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This will work for **bootstrap 4v**

The class names have changed quite dramatically:

- **.bs-tooltip-bottom**
- **.bs-tooltip-top**
- **.bs-tooltip-right**
- **.bs-tooltip-left**

example:

```
.bs-tooltip-bottom { 
    margin-top: 10px; 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks your solution is working, I was wondering if is there any way to apply css only to specific tooltips

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap.css you will find this code:

```
.tooltip.top {
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin-top: -3px;
}

.tooltip.right {
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.tooltip.bottom {
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.tooltip.left {
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin-left: -3px;
}
```

Change or override margins to change distance of tooltip from hovered elements.

I.E. To set bigger distance for top position of tooltip, set `.tooltip.top` class like this:

```
.tooltip.top {
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin-top: -70px;
}
```

Comment: rly thanks, i accepted the other answer just cause of he was faster in replying me ;)

Comment: No problem, that's fair ;)

Comment: What if I want my .tooltip.top for specific div class only

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap 5 you can use

```
data-bs-offset="10,10"
```

See [tooltips](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/tooltips/)