# Changing the position of a specific tooltip

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and their tooltips and have a similar question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601451/twitter-bootstrap-how-to-add-some-more-margin-between-tooltip-popup-and-elemen), i.e. I want to change position of a tooltip.

However, in my case I don't want to change the position of all tooltips but just the one below (I want to move the tooltip 30px to the left).

```
<i data-placement="left" title="{% trans "View the tool menu" %}" data-original-title="{% trans "View the tool menu" %}"
class='tooltip-hover menu-handle sprite-io sprite-control2'></i>
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/5XJEKbL.png]

How could that be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing position on a specific tooltip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20492913/changing-position-on-a-specific-tooltip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This changes position for all the tooltips that are placed to the left.

```
[data-placement=left] + .tooltip .tooltip-inner, 
[data-placement=left] + .tooltip .tooltip-arrow { margin-right:30px; }
```

If you want to only change for this element, give it a class or id.
ex:

```
#dummy + .tooltip .tooltip-inner, 
#dummy + .tooltip .tooltip-arrow { margin-right:30px; }
```